# Validation error when trying to apply a custom resource to a cluster: Required field is empty even though it is part of an optional parent object

Tags: go, operator-sdk

I am building a k8s operator using [operator-sdk](https://sdk.operatorframework.io/docs/), which manages custom resource called `Module`:

```golang
type Module struct {
    metav1.TypeMeta   `json:",inline"`
    metav1.ObjectMeta `json:"metadata,omitempty"`
    Spec   ModuleSpec   `json:"spec,omitempty"`
    Status ModuleStatus `json:"status,omitempty"`
}

type ModuleSpec struct {
    App string `json:"app"`
    WorkflowSettings WorkflowSettings `json:"workflowSettings,omitempty"`
    WorkerSettings WorkerSettings `json:"workerSettings"`
}

type WorkflowSettings struct {
    RunAfter []RunAfterConfig `json:"runAfter"`
    InputMapping Mapping `json:"inputMapping,omitempty"`
    OutputMapping Mapping `json:"outputMapping,omitempty"`
    FieldsProjection []string `json:"fieldsProjection,omitempty"`
}
```

`ModuleSpec` has an optional field `WorkflowSettings`. `WorkflowSettings` in turn has required field `RunAfter` and butch of other optional fields. When I apply a custom resource instance where `ModuleSpec.WorkflowSettings` field is not present (it's optional an optional field) as a yaml file - everything is ok. But then in operator's reconciliation loop I'am trying to update some of the metadata fields of this CR instance (`ObjectMeta`) and got validation error from kube api:

```
"Module.module.dev.module \"test-module\" is invalid: [spec.workflowSettings.runAfter: Required value, <nil>: Invalid value: \"null\": some validation rules were not checked because the object was invalid; correct the existing errors to complete validation]"
```

It seems to me when golang struct `Module` is initialized, every not filled field has default values. API client tries to apply it with all this default values to the cluster and we got validation error: `spec.workflowSettings` is now present but `spec.workflowSettings.runAfter` is empty.


Please help me to resolve this issue.